# iOS 8: fixing position of div not working + non functioning anchor tags (codepen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css-position, anchor

## Intro

I have a simple web page: http://codepen.io/giancarloGiuffra/full/OVYERO (it uses bootstrap)

To illustrate the structure, the html is as follows (simplified):

```
<nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
  <section id="home" class="row img-cover">
  </section>
  <section id="portfolio" class="row img-cover">
  </section>
  <section id="about" class="row img-cover">
  </section>
  <section id="contact" class="row img-cover">
  </section>
</div>
```

In the css file I set the background images of the 4 sections and I use javascript to assign to each section the dimensions of the viewport. I was using only css to do this (vh units) but it was not working in iOS, I was constrained to use javascript to make it work:

**css**

```css
.img-cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
#home {
 background: url(urlToImage);
}
...
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
//function declaration
  function changeVhWithPx() {
    var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    $(".img-cover").css({
      height: height,
      width: width
    });
  };
  //apply function
  changeVhWithPx();
  $(window).resize(changeVhWithPx);
```

There is also some javascript/jquery to change the opacity of the different sections as the user scrolls the page.

## Question

It functions as intended in desktop (chrome, firefox, safari, iexplorer latest versions) and in android but it doesn' work well in iOS. The main problems in iOS are the following:

1. The navigation bar doesn't stay on top part of the viewport, when scrolling down it disappears.
2. The anchor tags don't work, they simply are supposed to jump to different sections of the page, but in iOS it seems that they just reload the page.
3. The callback function that changes the opacity of the sections doesn't bind to the scroll event.

To solve problem number 1 I explicitly specified the following in my css file (even though i was already using bootstrap class *navbar-fixed-top*):

```css
#nav-bar {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0px !important;
}
```

It didn't work though. Then I decided to use javascript even though it should be css territory:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#nav-bar").offset({top: $(window).scrollTop(), left: 0});
});
```

But no luck either.

For problem number 2 and 3 I really haven't come up with a solution and haven't been able to find anything about such behavior in iOS.

Thanks for any help.

## Update 1:

I have found that for some reason (that i'm bound to discover) the scroll event is not triggered. So regarding point 3 the problem is not the binding but the fact that the event is not fired.

## Update 2:

I have deployed the same website to heroku. Everything works except for the anchor tags (so points 1 and 3 are solved). I will check with the guys in codepen to understand how come the same code works differently(better) in another platform.

## Update 3

Actually anchor tags are working as well in heroku, i thought they were not working because the hover event was being translated into a click so i had to double click to get redirected by the link.